# Not able to execute the vbs using command prompt

Tags: vbscript, registry

i have a piece of code in the form of vbs that i have used to convert the excel file to csv.
But when i execute the below code using command prompt i am getting error "There is no file extension in c:\source code"

command

```
    cscript //d //Nologo C:\\Source code\\Folder1\\FileConverter.vbs  C:\\Source code\\Folder1\\Book1.xls C:\\Source code\\Folder1\\Book1.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cscript //d //Nologo "C:\Source code\Folder1\FileConverter.vbs"  "C:\Source code\Folder1\Book1.xls" "C:\Source code\Folder1\Book1.csv"
```

You need to use quotes around paths with spaces